# how exit sub in cancel input box

Tags: excel, vba

i want save chart to png format, (inputbox my png name)

my code is

```
Sub savechartaspng()
    Dim fname As String
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    If ActiveChart Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    fname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & InputBox("filename") & ".png"
   ActiveChart.Export FileName:=fname, filtername:="png"
     MsgBox "saved"
End Sub
```

how inputbox = cancel or closed to exit sub and Do not save ?

tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the input from the InputBox first, check check to see if it's blank or not, and only continue if it's not blank.

```
Sub savechartaspng()
    Dim fname As String

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    If ActiveChart Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    fname = InputBox("filename")
    If fname = "" Then Exit Sub

    fname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & fname & ".png"
    ActiveChart.Export FileName:=fname, filtername:="png"

    MsgBox "saved"
End Sub
```

<sub>Note: It might be a goof idea to also have code that checks to make sure the user did not enter any characters that cannot be used in filenames too.</sub>

Comment: tnx braX, open double inputbox , how open just one inputbox

Comment: refresh the page - you probably copied it before i was done editing it